# How to filter Android adb shell logcat using multiple tags at one time?

Tags: android, adb, logcat

As we know, we can use the command to filter the log in Android:

```
adb shell logcat | grep "tag1"
```

Then, the logs which contain the tag1 will be output.

Now, I want to use one command that can output the logs which contain the tag1 and tag2.

I'm try to use, but it cannot work.

```
adb shell logcat | grep "tag1 tag2"
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is how to use grep properly:

```
adb shell logcat | grep -E "tag1|tag2"
```

Or you could just use logcat's built-in filters:

```
adb logcat -s tag1:* tag2:*
```

Comment: @Bastet, I used `-s` to set the default filter to silent. Your command is redundant.

Comment: P, pardon, I did this without `s`, thus made this misunderstanding, thanks for pointing out :)